# LMAX's disruptor pattern: is there a port to C++?

Tags: c++, disruptor-pattern

There are open source [Java](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/) and [.NET](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor-net/) versions of LMAX's Disruptor pattern, as described in the video [LMAX - How to Do 100K TPS at Less than 1ms Latency](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/LMAX). Here is [more links to information on the Disruptor pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559308/how-does-lmaxs-disruptor-pattern-work).

Is anyone aware of a port of the [Disruptor pattern](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/LMAX) to C++, either finished or in beta?

**Update**

Apparently [others are calling for a C++ version](http://mdavey.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/c-disruptor/) of the Disruptor pattern.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is already a functional C++ port. See http://www.2robots.com/2011/08/13/a-c-disruptor/.

Comment: Project's code moved to https://github.com/fsaintjacques/disruptor--

Comment: do someone know if it compiles under Windows?

Comment: i've tried to compile in Windows but received several errors. `DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN` is unknown macros and also `gettimeofday` function is linux-only. But it seems most part of the code is pretty portable, it's sad that these several places is not surrounded with "WIN32" ifdef...

Answer (score 3):

From the above link ("others are calling.."), comments:

Thread for discussing upcoming C++ port of the Disruptor pattern: http://groups.google.com/group/lmax-disruptor/browse_thread/thread/4a47a0a9b5837ca2

Performance of C++ version of Disruptor: approx. 22 million messages per second, with batching this reaches up to 100 million messages per second, see:
http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/08/inter-thread-latency.html

Comment: Is it possible to write a port in c#? Asking this question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097372/can-the-lmax-disruptor-be-ported-to-c

Comment: The C# port is available at http://code.google.com/p/disruptor-net/

Answer (score 2):

There is a free version called hmbdc-base.rpm that can be downloaded from:

https://bitbucket.org/hmbd/hmbdc-rel/downloads

It supports CentOS 7, and doesn't rely on virtual functions, sub microsecond delay, very fast.

It also has reliable subscribe / publish multicast messaging support.