# Can the LMAX Disruptor be ported to C#?

Tags: c#, disruptor-pattern

I know some people are working on a C++ port.

Is a C# port possible? In particular I'm thinking about the limitations around volatile fields being only 32-bit in C#. If that's the only problem, does anything think it worthwhile to write that ring buffer to only have the number of slots allowed in 32-bits. That's many many fewer events in the lifetime of the system. Do I have this right? Can we wrap back to 0 at some point?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It already has been ported to C#: http://code.google.com/p/disruptor-net/