# Should every read for cross thread variable to be on volatile or Atomic or being wrapped by synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Can I say that if a variable can be modified by other thread, I can never safely read it without a memory barrier?

Comment: Yes. Even Disrupor use memory barriers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559308/how-does-lmaxs-disruptor-pattern-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes pretty much. If you write (w) to a variable in thread T1 and read (r) that same variable from thread T2, you need to have a happens-before relationship between (w) and (r) to get the guarantee that the result of (w) will be visible to (r). The Java Memory Model defines ([JLS 17.4.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5-320)) the situations where there is a happens before relationship:

- An unlock on a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock on that monitor.
- A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field.
- A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.
- All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a join() on that thread.
- The default initialization of any object happens-before any other actions (other than default-writes) of a program.