# What in C/C++ is the most suitable close in functionality to collection Disruptor in Java?

Tags: java, c++, c, collections, disruptor-pattern

Which of the existing collections of data in C/C++ is the most suitable close in functionality to collection(library) **[Disruptor](http://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html)** in Java?

http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/

The small description:

It is an extremely fast alternative using messaging queues in multithreaded programs. Framework which has "mechanical sympathy" for the hardware it's running on, and that's lock-free. And lots of efforts to avoid lock, CAS, even memory barrier.

Read more about it in the discussion: [How does LMAX's disruptor pattern work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559308/how-does-lmaxs-disruptor-pattern-work)

Comment: I don't know what the disruptor pattern is. But this seems to be a valid question.

Comment: Agreed, especially since the poster included a link to a project based on the Disruptor pattern, although this: http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/ is a better link.

Comment: Regardless of the link used it would be beneficial to include some details about what you are trying to accomplish. It would also be beneficial to include a short description of the pattern instead of relying solely on an external resource that may disappear in the future.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious  Ok, I added the small description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the same functionality, use a mutex protected queue.  If you want the same performance you should re-implement the disruptor algorithm in C++  or try this open source project: https://code.google.com/p/disruptor-cpp/

And for those who don't know, the Disruptor (unfortunate name) is a message passing technique that uses lock-free algorithms and pays close attention to issues such as cache conflicts, to deliver very high performance in cases where it can be used.  A company named LMAX came up with it and named it.  Martin Fowler (of Refactoring fame) is an advocate for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is already a functional C++ port. See https://github.com/fsaintjacques/disruptor--