# go-disruptor ringBuffer visibility discuss

Tags: go, disruptor-pattern

In [go-disruptor](https://github.com/smarty-prototypes/go-disruptor) project.
I would like to know how to guarantee that writing and reading of `ringBuffer` is thread safe. Because I found that the writing and reading of the `ringBuffer` are not locked, and the data that may be read may not be written into the `ringBuffer`.  Because of the MESI protocol, it does not guarantee good visibility.

```golang
func main() {
    writer, reader := disruptor.New(
        disruptor.WithCapacity(BufferSize),
        disruptor.WithConsumerGroup(MyConsumer{}))

    // producer
    go func() {
        reservation := writer.Reserve(1)
        ringBuffer[sequence&RingBufferMask] = 42 // example of incoming value from a network operation such as HTTP, TCP, UDP, etc.
        writer.Commit(reservation, reservation)

        _ = reader.Close() // close the Reader once we're done producing messages
    }()

    reader.Read() // blocks until fully closed
}

type MyConsumer struct{}

func (m MyConsumer) Consume(lowerSequence, upperSequence int64) {
    for sequence := lowerSequence; sequence <= upperSequence; sequence++ {
        index := sequence&RingBufferMask
        message := ringBuffer[index]
        fmt.Println(message)
    }
}

var ringBuffer = [BufferSize]int

const (
    BufferSize = 1024 * 64
    BufferMask = BufferSize - 1
)
```

I think the ringBuffer read operation needs to be locked to protect the visibility of the internal elements after being written.

I wrote a simple program to simulate go-disruptor production and consumption, and found some concurrency issues when accessing ringBuffer. But I don't know the difference between the writing method and go-disruptor. Below is my program.

```golang
    group := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    var nums = [1024 * 64]int64{}
    group.Add(2)
    i := &Cursor{}
    go func() {
        defer group.Done()
        j := i.Load()
        for j < int64(len(nums)) {
            j = i.Load()
            nums[j] = j
            i.Store(j + 1)
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        defer group.Done()
        j := i.Load()
        for j < int64(len(nums)) {
            j = i.Load()
            if j != nums[j] {
                fmt.Println(j, nums[j])
            }
        }
    }()
    group.Wait()
```

Cursor uses the definition in disruptor.

```golang
type Cursor [8]int64 // prevent false sharing of the sequence cursor by padding the CPU cache line with 64 *bytes* of data.

func NewCursor() *Cursor {
    var this Cursor
    this[0] = defaultCursorValue
    return &this
}

func (this *Cursor) Store(value int64) { atomic.StoreInt64(&this[0], value) }
func (this *Cursor) Load() int64       { return atomic.LoadInt64(&this[0]) }

const defaultCursorValue = -1
```

It prints random data such as

```
3 0
440 440
512 0
512 0
556 0
637 0
724 724
...
```

Comment: I don't understand why you think there needs to be a lock involved, but this isn't a forum for general discussion. If you want to learn how the algorithm works, you could start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559308/how-does-lmaxs-disruptor-pattern-work

Comment: totally agree with @JimB - is there a question here?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I wrote a simple program to simulate go-disruptor production and consumption, and found some concurrency issues when accessing ringBuffer. But I don't know the difference between the writing method and go-disruptor. Below is my program.
```go

Comment: Please see the code and output I added to the question.